# How to verify that the boost module is kicking in or not in highcharts

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, highcharts

I need to verify that the boost module is configured correctly. Is there any method to verify this. I tried with adding more data, but with boost and without boost I'm not seeing any differences.

> In all SVG based charting solutions including HighCharts, performance
> decreases after adding a couple hundreds of points to the chart.
>
> The process of adding so much objects (points) to a SVG based chart
> takes time and user interaction with these objects (like values,
> titles, tooltips etc.) feels slow. Because there is a limitation of
> SVG elements which you can add to DOM.
>
> HTML5 canvas technology does not have such limitations. But a pure
> HTML5 canvas solution lacks of SVGs strength like DOM access, sharp
> rendering between different screen solutions etc.
>
> So HighCharts engineers made a hybrid solution with using both SVG and
> HTML5 canvas technologies. They are drawing the graph on a HTML5
> canvas then copying the content of the chart to a SVG.
>
> This is how HighChart's boost.js works.

Is there any way to know the difference looking at the DOM?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Boost module adds many properties to the series object, for example `renderTarget`. However, if you want to compare DOM elements, you can see that there is an `image` instead of another group and paths or other SVG elements in `highcharts-series-group`:

[image]

---

[image]

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8Lab230q/